# How to reset a component's state on doing router.push for same component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, frontend, server-side-rendering

I am trying to reset the state on router.push
I have a header component having a search option, When a user Search Something router.push sends him to '/search/${search}'
So basically on the search Page(SSR)

on Search Component I Put limit and skip as well for loadMore Functionality, when I try to search something from the home page or any other page so it runs smoothly because the search page renders and skips, limit gets reset

**Problem** - My main problem is that When I try to search for something from Search Page then the skip and limit remain the same, In fact, router.push doesn't reset the state
But when I reload the page the state gets reset. Why is that?

*my router.push on header component* -

```
const Header = ({searched }) => {
  const [values, setValues] = useState({
    search: "",
  });
  const { search } = values;
  const router = useRouter();
  useEffect(() => {
    setHydrated(true);
    // getPage();
    // setValues({ ...values, search: searched });
    console.log(searched);
  }, []);
  if (!hydrated) {
    return null;
  }

return (
        <React.Fragment>
          <h1 className="d-flex align-items-center mb-3 justify-content-between">
            <span className="">Feature Request</span>
            <div className="d-flex align-items-center">
              <Input
                className="search"
                placeholder="Search Something..."
                value={search}
                onChange={(e) => {
                  setValues({ ...values, search: e.target.value });
                }}
              />
              <AiOutlineSearch
                onClick={() => {
                  router.push(`/search/${search}`);
                }}
                size={25}
              />
            </div>
          </h1>

          <p>Your Suggestion Matters</p>
        </React.Fragment>
      );
    }
```

My Search page -

```
import React from "react";
import { Button, Card, CardText, CardTitle, Col, Container } from "reactstrap";
import Layout from "../../components/Layout";
import Link from "next/link";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { searchData } from "../../api/page";
import { getCookie } from "../../api/auth";
import { useRouter } from "next/router";
import InfiniteScroll from "react-infinite-scroll-component";
const SearchPage = ({ data }) => {
  const [values, setValues] = useState({
    pages: [],
    skip: 0,
    limit: 5,
    hasMore: true,
  });
  const { pages, skip, limit, hasMore } = values;
  const router = useRouter();
  const token = getCookie("token");
  const getSearchedData = async () => {
    console.log(hasMore);
    await setValues({ ...values, skip: 0, limit: 5 });

    const search = router.query.search;
    await searchData(search, skip, limit).then((data) => {
      if (data.error) {
        console.log(data.error);
      } else {
        setValues({ ...values, pages: data, skip: 0 });
      }
    });
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    getSearchedData();
    console.log("UseEffect chal gya");
  }, [data]);

  const mapSearchData = () => {
    return pages.map((p, i) => {
      return (
        <div key={i} className="mt-4">
          <Card body className="manual-card">
            <CardTitle tag="h5">{p.title}</CardTitle>
            <CardText>{p.excerpt}</CardText>
            <Button color="primary" className="w-25" size="sm">
              <Link href={`/pages/${p.slug}`}>Go To Page</Link>
            </Button>
          </Card>
        </div>
      );
    });
  };
  const fetchMoreData = () => {
    console.log("Best");
    const search = router.query.search;
    let toSkip = skip + limit;
    searchData(search, toSkip, limit).then((data) => {
      if (data.error) {
        console.log(data.error);
      } else {
        const tempArray = [...pages, ...data];
        setValues({
          ...values,
          pages: tempArray,
          skip: toSkip,
          hasMore: !(data.length < limit),
        });
      }
    });
  };

  return (
    <Layout search={router.query.search}>
      <Container className="mt-5">
        <Col>
          {pages && pages.length ? (
            mapSearchData()
          ) : (
            <div className="">No Such Pages Present!</div>
          )}
          {hasMore && (
            <Button
              className="d-flex mx-auto my-4"
              color="primary"
              onClick={fetchMoreData}
            >
              Load More
            </Button>
          )}
        </Col>
        ;
      </Container>
    </Layout>
  );
};

export default SearchPage;

export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
  const { search } = context.query;
  // console.log(slug);
  if (!search) {
    return {
      props: { data: null },
    };
  }
  let result = null;
  try {
    const res = await fetch(
      `${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API}/pages/search/${search}`
    );
    result = await res.json();
  } catch (error) {
    return {
      props: { data: null },
    };
  }
  return {
    props: { data: result },
  };
}
```

When I am on any other page instead of the search page then router.push works fine it resets the skip and limit and fetches all data on starting

But when I am on the search page itself and I search something from there then skip and limit states don't change, data get fetched on basis of skip and limit
And on page reload I Get complete data with skip and limit with the initial state.

**In SHort** -
My page is having state values skip and limit.

Suppose i have searched *Test* and i got 15 items, if i have limit of 5, skip of 0
so 15 means my skip will be 10 and limit 5.

Now when i try to search *Best* and suppose i have only 2 items named best but they are not showing...because on that time, router.push runs on header component and search page reloads but skip value still 10 and not resetting thats my whole problem.

Answer (score 0):

Just reset the value before calling `router.push()` inside `onClick` callback of  `<AiOutlineSearch>`

Comment: router.push is on another component named header
while I want to reset state of Search Page's skip and limit so,
How do i reset values on router.push?

Comment: The same way you set the value on the page, but call `setValue()` before `router.push()`.

Comment: I can set the values on page because i have - Skip, limit on page's state but i don't have skip limit on header.
How do i overwrite page's state on changing values from header component.

Comment: Where do these values come from?

Comment: skip limit values are in a page, whereas router.push() is on a header component.
Header Component is different and Search Page is different.
How can i change skip and limit values on Search Page? when i do router.push on header component.

Answer (score 0):

Make these changes in Search Page:

```
useEffect(() => {
    resetState() // create a function to reset the state 
    getSearchedData();
    console.log("UseEffect chal gya");
  }, [data, router.query]); // so whenever your search query changes, the state would be reset and new data will be fetched.
```

Comment: Tried it but it doesn't work

Comment: If you could create a running code sandbox demo that reproduces the issue that we could inspect live that could save us the time of standing up a running example

Answer (score 0):

May be you should decouple your `values` state and `getSearchData` function.

```js
const [skip, setSkip] = useState(0);
const [limit, setLimit] = useState(5);
const [pages, setPages] = useState([]);

// Reset limit and skip states
useEffect(() => {
  setLimit(5);
  setSkip(0);
}, []); // Try with [react.query.search] if it doesn't work

// Call getSearchedData
useEffect(() => getSearchData(), [limit, skip, react.query.search]);

// Fetch data
const getSearchedData = async () => {
  await searchData(search, skip, limit).then((data) => {
    if (data.error) {
      console.log(data.error);
    } else {
      setPages(data);
    }
  });
};
```